# How to color pandas table by comparing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, styles

For example, I have a dataframe with two columns A and B. If A > B, I want to color the row red; if A <= B, I want to color that row green. Any idea how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

Comment: I've read it. But all its examples take only one value. I want to know how can I compare two values from the dataframe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html):

```
def highlight_greater(row):

    if row['A'] > row['B']:
        color = 'red'
    elif row['A'] <= row['B']:
        color = 'green'

    background = ['background-color: {}'.format(color) for _ in row]

    return background

df.style.apply(highlight_greater, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I tried it, an error occurred:  
ValueError: Function <function highlight_greater at 0x0000027925CD7620> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (417,)
Expected shape:   (417, 2)                                                                               417 is the number of rows in my dataframe and 2 is the number of columns. Do you have any idea why the result does not have a shape (417,2)? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to return a color value for each column in the row. Updated - let me know if that works.